# Should link-only answers be flagged?

Tags: support, flags, link-only-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571570/352552) in the 10K tools, which was flagged as not an answer.  Since it's only a link, I re-flagged.

The flag was declined as

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I can't stress strongly enough my lack of concern for the lost flag weight—as Shog has said, losing flag weight is like burning monopoly money.  But should link-only answers be flagged?  Part of the description for the "not an answer" flag is that the answer should be a comment.

Was this just a result of a mod being distracted on a Friday afternoon?