# Why was my link only answer flag for this question declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers

Why was my (Link only answer) flag for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17936249/395659) question declined with the message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention

Comment: See: [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505) | [Should link-only answers be flagged?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118210) | [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183603) . We're far from consensus.

Comment: The links above dont answer my question, this was a link only answer on which was a comment asking the user to provide parts of the answer, what else should this post be falgged as? or do you see this post as ok and it should not be flagged at all?

Comment: Seems like those links above answer your question to me.  ChrisF posted the correct comment (presumably after declining your flag) to the answer.

Comment: I declined your flag. You can [read my answer in the linked post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183658/16587) as to why, or you can read [Cody's really great answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191035/16587) below.  They both say the same thing.  In all fairness, there were other flags on the post that were 'not an answer', and 'very low quality', neither of which were accurate -- so it wasn't just your flag I was declining.

Comment: a friendly advice, next time wait for about two days after comment prior to flagging. This [won't guarantee you from decline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154922/165773 "as explained here") but if you come to meta pointing out that OP didn't do anything to address comment, your complaint will get more upvotes. (I know it feels like [having your hands tied behind your back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers#comment560982_183709) but oh well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, the answer was definitely problematic. But the message the moderator who declined your flag seems self-explanatory enough:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Think about it this way: what did you want a moderator to do with that answer? Here's my list:

- Edit the answer to fix the link
- Edit the answer to remove the link
- Edit the answer to include a summary of the solution
- Leave a comment suggesting that the poster further develop the answer, including a summary of the content from the linked page within the body of his/her answer
- Delete the answer outright

Now, how many of those things could you have done yourself? The only one that you couldn't (i.e., the only one that *requires the attention of a moderator*) is deleting the answer.

And while sometimes that is merited, I hardly think it is appropriate for a self-answer posted a mere 14 hours ago (perhaps even a shorter time ago when you first submitted the flag) by a new user. At least give them time to fix the problem, or help them out by fixing it yourself.

If and when those strategies fail, and if the answer is still useless, then you can flag it and ask a moderator to delete it. I doubt they'll decline that flag. If you want to make extra sure, don't use one of the canned flag reasons like "low quality"; click the "other" box and type an explanation.

Comment: I don't know when the flag was raised, but if the post was flagged *after* ChrisF posted his comment, then the reason for declining should be obvious.

Comment: I declined the OP's flag.  This is exactly my reasoning.

Comment: Thank you guys for explanation.