# First post to be tagged as "just a link answer"?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

Is it possible to mark first posts as *Just a link answer*?

It came to me [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15761025/1983854). I do not want to flag it, as in similar cases I flagged as *not an answer* but got a:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So what should we do in these cases?

Comment: On which answer was the flag declined with that message? The one that you link to seems to be a clear-cut "not an answer".

Comment: In fact now I see they were no link answers, but more-comment-than-answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242264/how-copy-data-from-excel-to-a-table-using-oracle-sql-developer/15642307#15642307 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803371/what-system-function-and-cp-command-return-in-c-linux/15748084#15748084

Comment: I think new users posting comment-answers should get a little slack as on StackOverflow you'll need 50 rep to comment. If they are otherwise on topic, I personally tend to give them an upvote to boost their rep a bit, so they can make do with a comment in the future.

Comment: @AndersUP No, you don't upvote crap that should be deleted. It takes future posts out of that review queue, meaning if they post the same crap again, it slips through the second time.

Comment: I agree we have to be nice with new users not to make this place too elitist. This can be achieved with proper explanations on flags and encouragement of posting again when they failed to do it properly. So a wider flag options would help to do so.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I see your point, and I don't just upvote crap. I certainly don't upvote 'just link answers'. But I do think that there is a borderline/bootstrap case with new users who want to be constructive and want to comment on an answer already given. What should they do? Regurgitating the answer already given as a new answer with their own comments tacked on isn't going to get them voted up. (And shouldn't, obviously). If they consistently post crap answers, they'll get voted down anyway.

Comment: @AndersUP *"What should they do?"* Answer another question that doesn't require commentary or asking for more details. If they post a good answer to that question, they'll quickly get enough rep to leave comments outright. That's the way the system is designed. Attempting to subvert its function just makes more crap for us to have to clean up.

Comment: Related: [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing where the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) comes in. We already have a flag reason for link-only answers. It doesn't matter if they're posted by brand-new users or people who have 973k reputation. If they don't answer the question, they should be flagged as **not an answer**. The explanation for this flag reason is:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

A link-only answer does not answer the question, and should probably have been a comment instead (or not posted at all), so it fits the criteria for the "not an answer" flag.

Of course, in some rare cases, you might think that the attempted answer has some merit. The link might contain some particularly useful information and you might want to give the answerer the benefit of the doubt that they were trying to be helpful. In such cases, you have a couple of options:

1. Post a comment on their answer, explaining that link-only answers are not considered acceptable answers on Stack Overflow and gently prodding them to improve theirs following this guidance. Some of our users have crafted "stock" comments for this purpose. You'll see them posted to lots of link-only answers on the site. For example:

   > Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.
2. Downvote the answer because, as the tooltip on the down arrow says, "This answer is not useful".
3. If it's a subject you know something about yourself, and you are willing to take the time, edit the answer yourself and add in a summary of the information found on the linked page. We don't *expect* you to do this, of course, because it's a lot like posting an answer of your own. But it's certainly an option that you should feel free to exercise at your discretion.

Comment: Jon Skeet would resent not being used as the highest rep example except Jon Skeet is so humble he knows that you really meant to refer to him when you said 973k rep.

Comment: I intentionally picked a rep value higher than even Jon has earned thus far. Someday I suppose he'll get there. Think of it as allowing room for future growth.