# What should be done with questions where the question and answer are 404 on jsfiddle?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, jsfiddle, link-rot

This is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569986/jquery-register-click-event-twice **(10k)**

It seems like it should be a candidate for close and deletion-- this is no longer really a question and the answer is no longer really an answer.

This seems like a stupid sort of content to tolerate:

- Q: Can you answer my question at this page? (404)
- A: Yes, I have answered it here: (404)

Comment: Burn it... With fire...

Comment: "deleted by Bill the Lizard♦ just now" - well that didn't last very long...

Comment: There was an actual working jsfiddle in there that combined with the accepted answer could of salvaged that for future users. That said I upvoted @Mysticial's comment.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: This boils down to the exact reason [link only answers should be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), or moved to comments. The question was link only, the answer was link only, maybe it was helpful at one point, but now it's junk.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, those are strong candidates for closure and deletion. Vote and/or flag accordingly when you see these. (Your example is now 10k-only.)

Answer (score 7):

This question should most certainly be closed as not A real question:

> This question is ambiguous, vague, **incomplete**, overly broad, or rhetorical and **cannot be reasonably answered in its current form**.

(emphasis mine)

It can't be reasonably answered, so it's not a real question.

Note that if you're able to determine what the question is and can answer it without the fiddle (which is how the question should have been asked to begin with to protect against this behavior) then just edit out or fix the JSFiddle link instead.

As for the answers,  if the question is no good just ignore them.  Don't work yourself up with problems in answers until the question is fixed up.

If the question is fine and the issue is just with an answer then simply ask yourself if it an answer to the question even without the JSFiddle link (any good answer should be).  If no, then it is "not an answer" and should be flagged as such.

In this particular case it's also clear that there's really no recovery possible for the question, so it's been deleted.  In cases where it might still be possible to fix the problems and edit the question into a real question and answer again then it wouldn't need to be deleted.