# Moderator deleted question which had significant value

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators

I have 18,000+ reputation on Stack Overflow, so I understand the importance of closing and deleting questions and answers which are of little value to the community or which may lead to opinionated instead of factual answers.

**Note: I'm not stating that I am the authority on which questions should be allowed; I'm simply stating that it's not my first time on Stack Overflow, so please take my statement with a grain of salt.**

However, I recently found one closed question (*[Has Apple fixed the CoreData + iCloud sync issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857154/has-apple-fixed-the-coredata-icloud-sync-issues)*) which deals with the ongoing issue of Core Data + iCloud syncing problems, and it is one which could be legitimately answered based on facts. There were quite a few good answers that gave more detail into the problem, and the original question wasn't that bad compared to many others I have reviewed.

I edited the person's question to improve its clarity and flagged the post for review since I felt that it was unjustly closed, especially for a question that is really important to a large pool of iOS developers going through this same issue.

As a response, the moderator who originally closed the question just deleted the question and all answers instead, essentially removing this important resource for anyone trying to find more data about the issue at hand.

I really feel like this deletion was unnecessary and an overuse of moderator tools for no apparent reason. It's one thing to disagree with my flag to re-open the question, but you shouldn't blindly remove a valuable resource like this when limited data is already available on Google for solving this issue.

I have attached a screenshot of the edited question and the highest voted answer to this post and I ask that an unbiased person (e.g. not the moderator who deleted the post) please review this situation.

[image]

Comment: Take note that having 18k doesn't mean that you know about the importance of closing and deleting. Not questioning it of course, but there are 50k users who don't have a clue about it.

Comment: The question was listed as a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012015/how-to-save-core-data-to-icloud (in the flags)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Doesn't warrant its deletion though.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I understand that, but I wanted to preface my question so that you understood that I'm not "new" to the process like many people who question why a moderator deleted their question/answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It's not standard practice to delete duplicates, especially when they have existing answers which add more value to the discussion.  Typically, duplicates are closed and then the duplicate question/answer is linked so others can eventually find the solution.

Comment: @iWasRobbed I'm not sure links provide the value we're looking for here.

Comment: The OP is asking for a tutorial. Come on. That is NARQ for SO.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The foundation of the question was "is this even achievable" not "show me a tutorial".. Editing the question to remove the request for links is much more appropriate than deleting it.

Comment: Never should have been deleted, just my opinion.

Comment: @iWasRobbed "Is this achievable" fits into the "if a book can be written about this" requirement of NARQ.

Comment: @casperOne I would agree with you in many cases; in this case, the question is in the context of having issues with current versions of iOS and whether Apple has fixed their technology or not.  It's not a matter of "how do I do this" but "is this possible at all using their API"?

Comment: Note: that question has since been merged into *[Syncing Core Data across multiple devices using iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012015)*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reputation has no bearing on 'understanding closing and deletion on Stack Overflow'. I could link you to lots of high reputation users that love questions that are demonstrably not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

We all have our biases.

In this particular case, the question has a few problems:

- It's asking for link only answers.  [That's bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), as we've talked about repeatedly in the past
- The question [is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012015/how-to-save-core-data-to-icloud), so even if it were going to be undeleted, it'd still stay closed (and possibly even merged with the other question that would be closed since it's asking for link only answers).
- [The 'best' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859517/16587) to the question you linked to doesn't describe how to actually solve the problem.

There *may* be value there, but we don't want to encourage these types of questions and answers.

If the question asked, "How do I do use Core Data to save data across multiple devices" and there was an answer *with code*, then that'd be a great question and answer. If the answer was just 'See here', then there's no reason to keep it around (as soon as the link changes or the information in the link changes, or the link dies, the answer becomes useless).

I disagree with your assertion that this question has 'significant value'. I think it has the potential, but all the answerers so far have taken the easy way out of just giving out links, instead of putting actual answers in their post -- thereby diminishing the value of the question.

Should the question have been deleted? I'm not so sure.  But if we respond to flags on these answers and [delete them because they're link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), what's left?

I've undeleted and merged the question with its duplicate.

I've [tried to edit its duplicate into shape](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12012015/2), but it's in danger of deletion as well.

Why?

All the answers are link only. If all the answers are flagged and deleted, that's a symptom of a bad question. Maybe this question is too far gone.  It needs someone to take the time to edit the answers into shape. Be that someone.

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree.  StackOverflow was formed on the premise of collecting breadcrumbs for understanding and solutions to solve existing issues.  Blatantly deleting a post because it touches on the same topic as another question is unnecessary.  As I said in my question, it's one thing to disagree with my request to reopen the question, but it was unnecessary to take the additional step of deleting the question and all answers when they actually did provide value to finding a solution.  Many answers aren't the "best" solution, but they leave enough breadcrumbs to find it.

Comment: @iWasRobbed The question is asking for link only answers.  We don't want that kind of question here. If the question asked for code and people provided code in their answers, it'd be ok. You're focusing on the wrong issue.

Comment: As I said above, the foundation of the question was "is this even achievable" not "show me a tutorial".. Editing the question to remove the request for links is much more appropriate than deleting it.  I'm hoping you will make things right.

Comment: @iWasRobbed All those answers are literally deletable. If people flag them, you're going to get moderators deleting them because they're link only. There's no lasting value unless people take the time to edit the information *into their answers*.

Comment: I could make that argument for at least 25% of the answers on StackOverflow, including some by moderators that simply link to their previous answers on a different question (everyone's done it and you know it).  The point is that there are many difficult issues that we all face and we need breadcrumbs to show us how to find the solution.  Prematurely deleting those breadcrumbs because they don't exactly match a certain criteria means that a real solution may never be found and eventually posted.

Comment: Thank you for undeleting and merging the question.

Comment: @iWasRobbed "I can't do the right thing because it's too hard." Is what got the internet into this mess. We expect more effort from people now than we did even 3 years ago, because we realize what a mistake it is to allow link only answers. If you don't want the answers deleted, you should probably take the time to edit them into shape.

Comment: You are in the unique position of being part of the solution as well as being part of the problem.  StackOverflow has come a long way in trying to rank and review answers, but there is still a lot of work before the system can detect whether an answer has substance or whether it is of low value.  Currently, all I can review are new answers by new users; that leaves all the other low-quality answers that high rep users can still leave.

Comment: @iWasRobbed If you feel that 25% of answer on SO are link only answers then go flag them.  It doesn't matter if the poster has 1 rep or 100k, or whether they're a mod or not, it will be addressed.  The existence of other posts that violate the rules isn't an excuse to continue that behavior, or justification for why you can't handle these appropriately.  If there are other link only answers out there *they* need to be fixed instead of saying that these can't be.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with certain parts of SO's criteria for answers and believe that in some scenarios it is okay to leave certain answers which may provide clues to finding the real answer (especially if it's the only answer for a question).  Deleting 100% of answers just because they don't match a rigid criteria means more users hit a dead end.  There have been many times that Googling for a solution lead me to an answer which lead me to a different answer that finally solved my problem.  Destroying the first answer means it takes much longer to eventually find a solution.

Comment: @iWasRobbed Then rather than flagging them for deletion edit them into shape by quoting/summarizing the relevant link and bringing the content into SO proper.  If the edit would be too radical then post your own answer.  The design of the no-link-only-answers rule is not to make the poor-okay content go away, but rather to replace it with much better content, and also so that people post great content to begin with knowing that if they would have been lazy and only posted a link it would be deleted.  Also note that links can be okay in comments; these answers can be converted to comments.

Comment: As a note, I added a more detailed answer with an alternative approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/16615668/308315 .. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take note that moderators rarely operate without flags. Someone flagged the question as a duplicate of **[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857154/has-apple-fixed-the-coredata-icloud-sync-issues)**. As to why it's been deleted, I'm not sure. The operating moderator thought it was best.

You did well in bringing this here, where you can request clarification.

Comment: If it was a duplicate of another question, then that question should have been linked and the question closed using that description.  Deleting a valuable post that had detailed answers is just unnecessary in my opinion.