# Warn about similar links in comments/answers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

OK, say, we have a popular question with a lot of comments and answers. It can be a lot of links there and the bigger is their amount, the more probably you can miss such link.

While inserting links in my own answer, it would be nice if I'll be warned somehow that this link is already mentioned in other answers. Technically it is not difficult and most probably better to be solved on client side. As for UI - well, there is actually a room for discussion how it's better to be implemented.

But I'm asking only about concept, so my question is humble) Should we bother about repeating links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is a nice idea, I have to ask what problem you want to solve with it? To me this sounds like you're talking about those special community-wiki-poll-questions which are only around because somebody painted the delete button blue.

Duplicate answers (*not C&P*) are welcome and partly even encouraged as long as they add something of value (different wording, further explanations, more information, different perspective etc.). If your answer [merely consists of a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers) (and therefor you need to check if that link was already posted) you might want to rethink posting that answer at all. If the question has so many answers that you can't read through all the answers (for whatever reason), you might also want to reconsider posting there.

Comment: reducing possibility of **unnecessary** duplicate information, that what I keep in mind while writing this post. It's pretty like harvesting the energy -   it could be just several percents. But you can be right, actually, may be this is not the case.