# Is "This should be a Comment" feature removed?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, convert-to-comment

**My question is different from [Should there be a policy about 'One-Link-Only-Answers'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers)**

even if you see above question comment Marc has commented "if the link is only to a SE post, it is automatically converted to a comment" .. then why it does not happen in below case.

I am referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20345629/1230248).

This answer just refers another answer on Stack Overflow. I do remember (when I don't know) that when I tried to do same thing, meaning, tried to refer another answer in my answer, the system has said that this should be comment and automatically posted my answer in comments section under the question. And I think that was right too because if we just refer only another answer then it should be rightfully a comment only. In that case, why has this answer been accepted as answer or even got posted as an answer?

But this does not mean I have a problem with answer because the answer seems to be is correct and I have upvoted it as well.

Comment: It does not work that often. I have the feeling the conversion rules are pretty tight.

Comment: May be something like *try this link* would have auto-converted it to a comment.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers

Comment: One thing I can think of is the author was aware of that mechanism so his original post was just text then he edited quickly to add the link. Win.

Comment: see [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the count of characters in the body of your answer (*not counting the link*) is greater than **55** then an answer is not going to be converted to a comment automatically.

Posting a link-only answer converts it to a comment automatically. If there is any text included in the body that overcomes the system requirement then the answer will not get converted automatically.

See my last comment in the comments section -> I posted it as an answer but was automatically converted to a comment.

Here is the proof

[image]

---

Ok, so if you're answering a question and do this

[image]

and hit `Post Your Answer` then your answer will automatically be converted to a comment.

Conclusion : the feature is working but its requirement is 55 characters are required (not counting the link ) the amount of characters in the answers body.

Comment: what do u mean with this answer ??

Comment: But this does not explain why the linked link-only answer was *not* auto converted to comment. That's the real question here.

Comment: @Dhaval the feature is working. Trying to demonstrate that - the only thing I need to find out is how many characters are required within the body to NOT get converted to a comment

Comment: OK now with the edit it's a reasonable guess.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess my guess was good -> see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209705/is-this-should-be-a-comment-feature-removed/209736#209736)

Comment: @mehow nice, that linked answer got indeed 60 characters except  the link.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 56 characters? (*don't count spaces*)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and exclude the link.

Answer (score 1):

0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 012345

[Is "This should be a Comment" feature removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209705/is-this-should-be-a-comment-feature-removed/209730#209730)

Comment: this is a proof that once the body is over 55 characters the answer is not considered a link-only answer.