# How does Stack Exchange decide if an answer is trivial enough to make it a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, convert-to-comment, trivial

I just wrote an answer to a question and it was automatically converted to a comment for being 'trivial'. What are the criteria of a trivial answer?

The answer was posted here but has since been edited to exclude a link.

I'd prefer if the answer to this question was not specific to what happened to me, but rather to explain in general what might be considered a trivial answer.

[trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546083/xcode-get-contacts-out-of-address-book-who-also-use-the-application?noredirect=1#comment30723872_20546083)

Comment: Can you link that answer ?

Comment: Link to a post in the same site and less than 30 characters in addition to the link makes it trivial. You edited your comment so we can't know what your answer looked like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answer was too short. Please include more content and try to explain your answer.

This is ironic because my answer is short.

Comment: But it does not contain a link, thus not converted. :)

Comment: Good to know.  Do you have a source for the 30 character info?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thought it was one or the other ... well well I will need to study my books a little more.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd - well, you can't submit answer with less than 30 non space characters to begin with so the common way to reach over 30 without actual content is links.

Comment: @JuJoDi no official source, just trial and error made at some point. (30 makes sense, as it's the post character limit to begin with :))

Comment: ``+1 for irony``

Comment: I thought the limit was [55 chars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209730/212780)?

Comment: -1 because you tried to explain the irony, thereby making your answer not as short as it should have been.

Comment: @Generic yeah, 55 was too hard to remember... my bad. Still, close enough.