# Flag answers that only link to a duplicate questions answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to answer a stackoverflow question with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stackoverflow-question-with-a-link)

In this SO question: [Download a file part by part in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947087/python-download-a-file-part-by-part)

[This "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947087/python-download-a-file-part-by-part/7947127#7947127) simply links to a [duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python) and adds some "filler" text.  In my opinion this should be a comment, but in general, should answers like that be flagged for a moderator to convert to a comment (or do whatever mods do to flagged answers)?  Or is it considered acceptable to post an answer that is just basically a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to post links, but it's preferred if some extra text is added, and even better if at least a synopsis is given in case the link dies in the future.  That particular answer is inbetween; better than a link only, but could use more explanation.

The thing that really matters though is if it answers the question.  People ask questions because they want an answer, so the OP getting his answer is what's most important for the site to be useful.  Since the OP hasn't accepted it yet, or commented on it, we don't know whether the answer was sufficient or not.

Those kind of answers should not be flagged.  You can edit it some of the explanatory information if you'd like, or leave a comment for the poster prompting him to do it as random did in the linked answer.

Comment: It wasn't tongue-in-cheek. It was a vague answer that is prone to a shifting reference point. A bad answer for all.

Comment: @random, my edit passed your comment as it was speeding my way.

Comment: @random & Lance - Thanks for the info.  Im wondering, now that the answer in that question has been edited with more content, how (if at all) can I revoke my flag as it is still "waiting for review"?

Comment: Wait... OP's question was about answers that link to other SO questions.  99% of the time they will only be "hey, I think this question will help you"; answers like this should be comments and will be deleted.  It should have been a vote to close as duplicate rather than an answer.  They should be flagged whenever seen.  If it is a full answer, and it links to related question (and is NOT a copy of an answer to that related question) then it is okay.