# Only link to one duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On Stack Exchange, often, when questions are closed as duplicates, they are closed as duplicates and linked to another duplicate! This can lead to long chains (I think the longest i've seen is 5 or 6, but [Flag answers that only link to a duplicate questions answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110654/flag-answers-that-only-link-to-a-duplicate-questions-answer) is the one that showed up when I was writing this question.) Shouldn't we just mark things as one common duplicate, or go back and look for all the dupes marked as dupes of dupes, or could we do it programmatically, or is it better for SEO or anything to have it be a duplicate of a duplicate, or does it just not matter.

Comment: oh, the irony..

Comment: @Roberts no, because the question it is suggested as a duplicate of is not a duplicate question!

Comment: This actually touches a very valid point - especially with questions with many dupes, many dupe-closings point to a mediocre original (that the user(s) in question happened to find with a quick search) as opposed to one ideal one. It might be very sensible to re-map such "dupe networks" and make them all point to the highest-voted, best-maintained original Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

If we see all duplicates of duplicates, at least we know which question is a duplicate of which, but having a common duplicate could be a good thing as well.