# Crawling for answers with bad links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The website's been around for nearly four years now, I suspect many of the links in the answers are broken and simply out-of-sight right now.

Could/Should we crawl URLs from answers over 6 months old for broken links?

Comment: I really like this idea.  Maybe even include the results as a tab on the review page for community clean-up.

Comment: Can we also crawl for all w3schools links and change them to MDN links?

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/feature-suggestion-flag-as-broken-link