# Fix links to broken git documentation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, hyperlinks, link-rot

There needs to be a link sweep to questions/answers in SO that are pointing to **http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/**.  Lots of google juice for git questions are pointing to these SO questions with these dead end links.

[Search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inurl%3A%22*kernel.org%2Fpub%2Fsoftware%2Fscm%2Fgit%2Fdocs%2F*%22)

Comment: Gads... I forgot to post about this from when we'd discussed it on Twitter. Thanks for remembering!

Comment: It seems the links were recently fixed to point to http://git-scm.com/docs/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are basically links to the manual, users should also look at the tag wikis to throw in the basic use case, examples, and the various flags that go with each of the Git commands.

You can rely on another third-party site to hold up and stick around with their repos, or sock that away on Stack Overflow.

Most of these don't really need the links and of the others, they could be annotated or replaced with the git call for the respective man pages.

The [git-reset](/questions/tagged/git-reset) [tag wiki is such a starter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-reset/info).

Comment: That's a great idea and I wonder how many folks like me didn't know that feature was even there

Comment: Are there any good tools, client side or online for converting Html (man pages) to markdown (which I assume is what the SO tag wikis are)?  I ran into another one for git-config that was tried to convert but ended up leaving it as it because the conversion process suxor'd.

Comment: Tag wikis use Markdown, but no idea on what tool to make it simpler to convert from HTML to Markdown

Answer (score 1):

Related see:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116442/17174

---

When these pop up I always feel we need a better way of catching and dealing with it.

I am counting 300 results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kernel.org%2Fpub%2Fsoftware%2Fscm%2Fgit%2Fdocs%2F%22

The bigger question is what should this be changed to?

Comment: It seems that git-scm.com (the new git site) has given the offical documentation link to Scott Chacon's (github) repo at http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html

Comment: @MotoWilliams I agree with random here, we should simply link to the appropriate tag wiki instead, that way the links are stable and we can always fix the tag wiki, that is one spot

Comment: That's makes sense and I'm not married to any given solution since I'm in user mode of "just fix it"