# Comment on an answer on a Site I am not amember of

Tags: feature-request, comments

Are there plans to be allowed to add comments to answers without becoming a member of the community?

[Scan barcode from the mobile screen itself](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34793/scan-barcode-from-the-mobile-screen-itself) has a link to the RedLaser website that states that RedLaser was shut down in Dec 2015. A comment to that effect might be useful but do I really have to join the community to comment?

Perhaps being able to comment anywhere once you reach a certain score/level/badge on any other StackExchange site.

Comment: see also: [For protected questions, require local reputation to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279098/165773)

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/feature-suggestion-flag-as-broken-link (same idea, just using flags instead of comments.)

Answer (score 14):

> Are there plans to be allowed to add comments to answers without becoming a member of the community?

No.

> A comment to that effect might be useful but do I really have to join the community to comment?

Yes.

Or - if you feel that the answer needs improvement (given that you want to comment on it) - **suggest an edit**, anonymously.

If you want to participate, join the community. It is a one-click operation.

> Perhaps being able to comment anywhere once you reach a certain score/level/badge on any other StackExchange site.

That could cause a lot more comments on questions that get attention (tweeted, hot network question, shared on other social media, etc...) by people who "drive-by".

---

Personally, I find the benefit of such a feature to be offset by the ease of joining (or suggesting an edit) and the potential problems with it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has such a feature ever been considered for offensive/spam flags?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - not that I know.

Comment: So you are saying that you'd rather **not** have comments about broken links and other simple stuff to avoid the risk of having too many comments on popular question. Wow!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - I am saying that as an anonymous user **you can suggest an edit**.