# Am I right to decline an offered bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, duplicate-questions

With reference to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16318417/2065121)

I just found the answer to the OP's question using Google and it turned out to have been previously asked/answered on SO. Therefore I just commented with a link to the answer, even though a small bounty was on offer.

Now the guy that offered the bounty (who was not the OP) suggested in a follow-up comment that I should make my comment an answer and he'll award the bounty.

I can't see that that's right, so I've not done so - have I followed the correct protocol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the question is a duplicate, flag it for moderator attention; a moderator can remove the bounty and mark the question as a duplicate. You cannot vote or flag as a duplicate yourself in that case, so moderator intervention is the only option.

I believe in that case the bounty reputation is refunded.

Not creating a duplicate answer as well is certainly the correct action.

Comment: As well, answers which are only links to other SO questions are subject to deletion, even with the accept checkmark and a bounty. You'd end up losing the bounty later anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've flagged the question and commented to the bounty owner for info.

Comment: @animuson: Is a bounty really lost when the answer receiving it is deleted? That doesn’t seem right.

Comment: @minitech Pretty sure it is, and I don't think the score/age threshhold locks bounties in either.

Comment: @minitechη That's correct.

Comment: Also note that moderators can only refund a bounty before it's awarded.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - I whole heatedly believe that **you have done the right thing**. Just comment with a link or VTC/flag as a dupe (depending on your reputation). Don't worry about the bounty "going to waste" as it has served its purpose by attracting your attention. That's the *real* purpose of a bounty after all - to *attract attention*.

Furthermore, regardless of a question with a bounty on it, answers consisting of only a link are [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stack-overflow-question-with-a-link) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stack-overflow-question-with-a-link). Even if the link is an internal link to Stack Overflow.

When someone posts an answer saying - some one else has already answered this and includes a link, I get the feeling that they are trying to ride on someone else's contribution for reputation. While I realize that this is not always the case, and it is usually just some user trying to help out by providing a useful link - this really doesn't constitute an answer in itself. It should be a comment (just as you have done).

I might be a bit drastic with my opinions but I really can't stand answers which only point to another answer. Even if you take the usual steps to include a summary of the linked post the user is still duplicating content. They should just link to the post in a comment and let the original author of the post receive the votes that they deserve.

Comment: Thanks - that's good to hear, and I feel the same way you do, I didn't do any work so I don't deserve the credit. It seems a shame that the bounty would otherwise get lost so I've flagged and hope that the bounty can get refunded as Martijn suggested.

Comment: I don't think it should be refunded at is actually did serve it's purpose by motivating you to help. It's like an advert in a newspaper - you pay for the placement. An advert doesn't guarantee that you'll get more customers :)

Comment: It's been refunded already. Hopefully the bounty owner decides to transfer it to the dupe.

Comment: @mar - now **that's** a great idea.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  I'm the bounty awarder in this affair (who has been refunded).  I would like to award the bounty to the answer on the original question.  If I put a bounty on the original question will it go directly to the already accepted answer or will it open it up for new answers?

Comment: @joh - an accepted answer is the opinion of only one person - the user who asked the question. As the user who offers a bounty - you have the choice to award the reputation to any answer **you** see fit.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick - If you feel that way inclined you can add a bounty and choose the option "Reward existing answer". You still need to wait 24 hours (IIRC) before actually awarding it though. But I wouldn't feel obliged to do it as Shog has 60K rep and you have less than 1K!

Comment: @mar -that's repcisim! ;) It's about recognition - not so much about the rep... A pat on the back is a pat on the back no matter how many you've received in the past.

Comment: @Lix - Yes that's true and this is bonus rep anyway.

Comment: @mar - as long as it's not meta rep ;)